# d3 pie: redraw label on path change

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3 to draw a pie with radio button to change the paths showed. My problem is to recalculate the label position based on the new paths. On load the labels are drawn correctly but on click the position still the same of first load.
I think that the problem is that the g's take only the first data value and i don't know how to say to take the current data values.

The function that draw the labels is

```
//Labels
    d3.selectAll("g").select("text").transition()
        .ease("linear")
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 0).remove();
    svg.selectAll("g").append("text")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            var c = arc.centroid(d),
                x = c[0],
                y = c[1],
                // pythagorean theorem for hypotenuse
                h = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            return "translate(" + (x / h * labelr) + ',' +
                (y / h * labelr) + ")";
        })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .style("fill", "#000")
        .style("font-size", 12)
        .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
            // are we past the center?
            return (d.endAngle + d.startAngle) / 2 > Math.PI ?
                "end" : "start";
        })
        .text(function (d) { return d.data.label; })
        .transition()
        .ease("linear")
        .delay(1000)
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 1);
```

For more info see https://jsfiddle.net/w0ckw4tb/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply new data binding before you append new text nodes:

```
svg.selectAll("g").data(pie) // <== !!!
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform" ...
```

If you did not do it, this code:

```
.attr("transform", function (d) {
    var c = arc.centroid(d),
        x = c[0],
        y = c[1],
        // pythagorean theorem for hypotenuse
        h = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    return "translate(" + (x / h * labelr) + ',' +
        (y / h * labelr) + ")";
})
```

returns the same value for `transform` attribute so the labels remain at the same place.

Check [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eL1017wg/).